# back to back or comparative stem and leaf plot for two groups within one data set(object)

Tags: r

[I need to make a stem and leaf back to back plot of the bone levels for breastfeeding women vs bone levels in control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUYup.jpg)

Comment: Please don't most images of code or data. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Stem and leaf "plots" aren't exactly very popular but there are tips for creating them here: https://r-coder.com/stem-leaf-r/. Maybe try those suggestions first and if you have trouble ask a more specific question later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.